# How to protecting stepper drivers from manual motion?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am trying to figure out a way to protect my stepper drivers from manual motion of the motor. To make this more clear, the system which these steppers are being built into allows for both computer controlled or manual controlled motion. I am concerned that if the manual motion is too quick, damage will result to the drivers. Is this something I should be worried about, and if so, is there a recommended way to electrically isolate the motor from the driver when under manual control? Thank you!

Comment: would the manual motion be faster than the automatic?

Comment: (other than that: the answer is probably "flyback diodes")

Comment: One possibility would be to use a variable-reluctance step motor.  They have no magnet and will not generate any back-EMF when turned off and moved manually.  Of course, they have no detent torque.  They will spin freely.